How to turn a tuple of lists into a list?
I am using Python 2.7 to turn a tuple of lists (of 2 elements) of float into a list of floats (([1.0],[2.0]) => [1.0,2.0]) like the following:
[tuple_lists[0][0],tuple_lists[1][0]]

Is there a pythonic 2.7 way to do so in a more elegant way?

Context and constraints are not clear (why do you have that?), but probably a list comprehension.

is numpy involved? what is the type() of your list?

What does "more elegant" mean, specifically?

If there is exactly one item in all the lists in the tuple, you can more idiomatically unpack them in a list comprehension:
[i for i, in tuple_lists]

You can also use chain.from_iterable to join the lists:
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(tuple_lists))

Or you can map the sequence to operator.itemgetter(0):
from operator import itemgetter

map(itemgetter(0), tuple_lists)

Zipping the lists of 1 item bundles them together as a tuple, though you'd have to access the tuple with an index of 0:
list(zip(*tuple_lists)[0])

Since in your case there are only two lists in the tuple, you can also simply use the add operator to join them:
from operator import add

add(*tuple_lists)

Demo here

[l[0] for l in tuple_lists]

l iterates over the lists in tuple_lists, each list having a single element.

any more elegant that that no possible? the tuple_lists is always of size 2

"elegance" is quite subjective. If always len(tuple_lists) == 2, then your original solution was just fine. Python lacks a "flatten" function.
